# using kendoui splitter class in angular

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

How can I use angular-kendoui with the splitter class? i have wrote

```
<div kendo-splitter k-option-orientation="horizontal" style="height: 600px; width: 100%;">
<div id="top_pane">
    <p>Left pane</p>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <p>Right pane</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

but how can I add the panes data?

ok, found it

```
<div kendo-splitter k-orientation="'horizontal'" k-panes='[{ collapsible: true, size: "0%" }
                                                    , { collapsible: false }
                                                    , { collapsible: true, size: "0%" }]' k-resize="onResize" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;">
<div>
    Incidents
</div>
<div>
    Video
</div>
<div>
    Sensors
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div kendo-splitter k-orientation="'horizontal'" k-panes='[{ collapsible: true, size: "0%" }
                                                    , { collapsible: false }
                                                    , { collapsible: true, size: "0%" }]' k-resize="onResize" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;">
<div>
    Incidents
</div>
<div>
    Video
</div>
<div>
    Sensors
</div>
```

Comment: So where is the difference? What was the problem and what is the solution?